# The Windows Search Service has failed to create the new search index

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I got this error in Event Viewer

> The Windows Search Service has failed to create the new search index.
>   Internal error <4, 0x8004117f, Failed to add project:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Projects>.

```
EventID: 1006
Level: Error
Task Category: Search service
Source: Search
```

At the same time, this error also occurs:

> The Windows Search Service cannot open the Jet property store.
>
> Details:  0x%08x (0x8004117f - The content index server cannot update
>   or access information because of a database error.  Stop and restart
>   the search service.  If the problem persists, reset and recrawl the
>   content index.  In some cases it may be necessary to delete and
>   recreate the content index.  (HRESULT : 0x8004117f))

```
EventID: 9000
Level: Error
Task Category: Gatherer
Source: Search
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the [solution](http://nctritech.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/services-windows-search-windows-defender-etc-failing-to-start-and-service-specific-errors-after-upgrading-to-a-larger-hard-drive-on-intel-platforms/) here and it has worked

Basically, you need update the Intel Rapid Storage Technology software to latest version from the [intel site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=&ProductID=2101&ProdId=2101)